# Is there a set for which no defining formula can be found?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756051/is-there-a-set-without-a-predicate), but since (1) it's a little unclear (in fact, it has even been *closed* as unclear), (2) I'm not familiar enough with the terminology of the answer to judge wheter or not it answers my question and (3) it's old enough for me to assume the commenters won't respond to it, I thought it would be better to ask.

In the book I've been using to study set theory, the author enunciates the Intuitive Principle of Abstraction in the very first chapter:

> A formula $P(x)$ defines a set $A$ by the convention that the members of $A$ are exactly those objects $a$ such that $P(a)$ is a true statement.

Thinking a bit more deeply into it, I noticed the author said nothing of the converse. That is, nothing was said if the following statement is true:

> For every set $A$ there is a formula $P(x)$ which defines it.

So, here I ask you all: is that statement true? Are there sets for which we can find no formula?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a set without a predicate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756051/is-there-a-set-without-a-predicate)

Comment: See question preamble.

Comment: Your question is unclear indeed. Do you allow $x\in A$ for $P(x)$ ? Your $A$ must come out of somewhere.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy if you're asking whether I am allowing for the trivial formulation of a set: $A = {x | x \in A }$, then no.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fact 1: Since a formula must be of finite length, and our alphabets are finite, the are only countably many formulas.

Fact 2: We usually assume (mostly implicitly) that there are uncountably many sets.

Assuming these two facts, we can conclude that the answer is yes, there must be sets without a defining formula. But we can't describe a single one of them.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you! Now, going out on a limb: are there any theories which relax fact #1 for theoretical purposes? That is, are there theories which allow for an uncountable "number" of formulas, say by allowing them to be infinite, recognizing that they wouldn't be practical to write?

Comment: @DanksC. I don't think so. At any rate, it doesn't change the answer because if it did work you get up to $2^{\aleph_0}$ formulas, but there are more sets than that.

Comment: I sse. Thank you!

Comment: Yes @DanksC, languages that allow infinitely long stateme tx

Comment: Here is a paradox.  All ordinals are finitely expressible for if there was any finitely  unexpressible ordinals, there would be a least finitely unexpressible ordinal that has just now been finitely expressed.

Comment: This argument was mentioned in a comment to the linked question.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Usually resolved by not being allowed to quantify over formulas in your formulas, so you can't express "finitely expressed". It's the same reason that comprehension and replacement aren't axioms, but axiom schemas.

Comment: I think your answer is misleading and contains some common misconceptions. The question of whether "every $A$ can be defined by some $P(x)$" has to be asked on a meta level, because inside a given model of set theory you cannot even define in a uniform way what "$A$ is defined by $P$" means. And in fact it is possible to have a model of sets where every set is defined in the above way, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_(set_theory).

Comment: @Jonathan This is addressed, albeit not explicitly, in my fact 2. Also, the OP was confused by the rigorous argument, so I have a simpler one on purpose.

Comment: @Arthur but you conclude in the end that there must be sets which are not definable. This is not true and this was even mentioned (although not very detailed) in the answer to the post that was linked.

Comment: @Jonathan Right. My answer is now more explicit about the fact that the conclusion follows from the two assumptions. That ought to be better.

Comment: @Arthur But it does not even follow from the assumptions you made. The point I was making is that the concept of "defining" that you are using in your argument is inconsistent (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem)